# Method not allowed get student by Id

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api

i'm following a tutorial.
We need to create a REST API to do basic crud operations on a student object.
I just wanted to add a get by id.

Here is my controller:

```
package com.example.demo.student;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="api/student")
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }


    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        return studentService.getStudents();

    }

    @GetMapping(path="{studentId}")
    public Optional<Student> getStudent(@PathVariable("studentId")Long studentId){
        return studentService.getStudent(studentId);

    }

    @PostMapping
    public void registerNewStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
        studentService.addNewStudent(student);
    }
    @DeleteMapping(path="{studentId}")
    public void deleteStudent(@PathVariable("studentId")Long studentId){
        studentService.deleteStudent(studentId);
    }

    // only update name
    @PutMapping(path="{studentId}")
    public void updateStudent(
            @PathVariable("studentId")Long studentId,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String name)

    {
        studentService.updateStudent(studentId, name );
    }
}
```

and my service :)

```
package com.example.demo.student;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class StudentService {

    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;
    @Autowired
    public StudentService(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }
    public List<Student> getStudents(){

        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void addNewStudent(Student student) {
        Optional<Student> studentByName = studentRepository.findStudentByName(student.getName());
        if(studentByName.isPresent()){
            try {
                throw new Exception("name taken");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }
        studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    public void deleteStudent(Long studentId) {
        boolean exists = studentRepository.existsById(studentId);
        if (!exists){
            throw new RuntimeException("student with id" + studentId + " does not exist.");
        }
        studentRepository.deleteById(studentId);

    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateStudent(Long studentId, String name) {
        Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(
                "student with Id" + studentId + " does not exist"
                )
        );
        if(name != null && name.length() > 0 && !Objects.equals(student.getName(), name)){
            student.setName(name);
        }
    }


    public Optional<Student> getStudent(Long studentId) {
        Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(
                        "student with Id" + studentId + " does not exist"
                )
        );
        return studentRepository.findById(studentId);

    }
}
```

Nevertheless, when I test .../api/student/1, I've this error:
"error": "Method Not Allowed",

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks guys :) Have a nice day

Comment: please post your controller class to see mapping of another endpoints. by the way, why do you call `studentRepository.findById(studentId)` twice and what's the point to return `Optional` from a controller?

Comment: What is the @RequestMapping("/") value at the level of your Controller class? Is it "api/student"? Show the class declaration with any annotations.

Comment: Unrelated to error, but consider changing Controller method signature to 
public ResponseEntity<Student> getStudent(Long studentId)
Requires import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

Comment: hey, @AndrewThomas , my post is edited

Comment: What client are you using? Postman? Are you sure you're calling it with HTTP GET and not POST, PUT or DELETE?

Comment: Try @GetMapping(path="/{studentId}")

Comment: Or @GetMapping("/{studentId}")

Comment: Great! See my video lecture course "Intro to Database App Dev w/Spring Boot, Angular, Postgres" at https://www.udemy.com/course/intro-db-app-dev-springboot-angular/?referralCode=3AB74AFDA723F00C4762

Answer (score 0):

@GetMapping("/{studentId}")